# Adding an element to the div if not already added via Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to include a custom button in every tweet that appears on the timeline.

```
var tweets = $(".tweet");
var len = tweets.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
    if($(tweets[i]).has(".custom-button-class").length){
        console.log("already added");
    }
    else{
        console.log("needs to be added");
        $(d).appendTo(tweets[i]); // d is the element that I am trying to append to every tweet
    }
}
```

I want the element to be added only if the tweet is already on the page and if the element is not already appended to it.
Please help, thanks :)

<strike>EDIT 1: This code adds the elements from bottom, how to add them from top? So that user doesn't see any lag(as most of times, user will be at top when refreshed)?</strike> **Done**
<strike>EDIT 2: If I use 2000 as refresh timer, it adds element to one tweet per refreshInterval. So, this delays the process of adding elements to every tweet. I want to add element to all tweets(to which not appended earlier) simultaneously. Possible?</strike> **Done**
<strike>See screenshot</strike>

[image]

Comment: Can you try reversing the loop i.e. starting from count-1 till 0

Comment: I tried exactly that(just before your comment). Thanks :)

Comment: Do i deserve a up vote ;)

Comment: Why do you say it's a waste of "bandwidth" here? Is your element loading some external resources that cannot be cached?

Comment: What I felt initially was - It keeps on loading new tweets which are to be loaded only when user scrolls down. But now looks like I was wrong in observation.
I will update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the button is already added with:

```
if(!$(tweets[i]).has(".custom-class").length) {
    $(d).clone().prependTo(tweets[i]);
}
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. It just keep on prepending the element to first tweet on the page at any time..

Comment: Ok, I understood - the problem is - In my for loop, in one execution of my function, only one value is executed. Not all. So, that's why.. one element is added to one tweet at a time. Any clue, why? How to do it right? @Ferret

Comment: Wow! It worked. Exactly what I wanted!
@Ferret, please update your above answer so that I can mark it as correct answer :)